# What difference step is happening while importing WSDL via browser Vs SOAPUI

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, glassfish-4.1

I have a well reported problem with a simple WS deployed in Glassfish 4.1 , where I get the WSDL in browser but cant import it in SOAP UI or Eclipse(Kepler) .

IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
WSDLException
WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR:
[this](http://:mycomputername::8080/TestMart/ProductCatalogService?wsdl)

My question is : What extra thing is happening while trying to access this location from SOAP UI / Eclipse WebService explorer Vs via browser ?
I would like to know what other areas I need to look at to trouble shoot this issue .

Comment: Please provide a working link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading a WSDL trough SOAP UI, it tries to parse it and does some validations of the WSDL in order to create a SOAP UI project and generate the empty requests for you. Eclipse also does these validations (On validate in the context menu, when a .WSDL is opened or when saving a .WSDL) - I've found them even more strict than the SOAP UI ones.

On the other hand, the browser doesn't do validation of the wsdl content, it just displays it as it is, and applies some default colours for rendering xml in order to make it more readable. But it would not complain if the wsdl is not formed correctly.

Comment: So I could assume that my WSDL is failing validations since its not even being read by SOAP UI or wsimport ?

Comment: These no way of telling with 100% certainty without reading the WSDL, but yes, you are safe to assume this.

Comment: Just confirmed that there is some issue since eclipse reported problem when I copied the WSDL to it's editor . Thrown at the very first line : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> and the error is : Description Resource Path Location Type
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. line 1 WSDL Problem . Would you know why this is ?

Comment: Maybe you've copied some uneeded text from the browser. Proper WSDL must look something like this: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/wsws-proceedings/uche/wsdl.html . Remove the first line and see if it works again.

Comment: Looks like the annotations that I use in classes are not updated in the server even after multiple refresh. So the corrections I make do not get reflected. The eclipse editor is now reporting that operation name ( which I set using webmethod annoation) is not found anywhere . Are you aware of any such issues with glassfish server 4.1 ?Thank you for your response..

Comment: Accepted the answer since it answers the question I posed. Thank you.

Comment: Just to assist those who might reach this page : It was WSDL that caused issue. Webmethod annotation to name the action and operation resulted in message parts that were not resolved by validation rules. .However , going with the default resulted in working WSDL and SOAP UI & eclipse svc explorer imported it neatly.

Comment: I cannot tell you about Glassfish, but if the operation is not found, it might be a problem with namespaces in the WSDL, a missing external XSD reference or simply spelling.If your WSDL refers to external XSD schema it is quite possible Eclipse cannot find it.

Comment: Looks like it was primarily glassfish failed to pick the updates properly. Just restarted the IDE , added webmethod annotation params one by one and republished everytime to ensure its picked up. All works fine now.